# image height is getting reduced in smaller screen when we use img-responsive class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `Bootsrap 3`. I gave `img-repsponsive` class to the img tag and the image width is getting resized according to the device width. But image height **is also getting reduced** which is making the image to look bad.

I **don't want the image height to be reduced**.

Please help me in solving this issue

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If both width + height aren't reduced the image will lose it's proportions / aspect ratio -- is that what you want?

Comment: @ Skelly : Thanks for your reply.I want the image height to be constant in all the screens only width should fit according to the device width

Comment: So, what you have to do its change the media query for img-repsponsive in order to no change the height. Or if you don't want to change this, you could create your media query and a special class for this situation.